# How to convert matrix to a stack of diagonal matrices based on every row?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix:

```
A = [1 1 1
     2 2 2
     3 3 3]
```

Is there a vectorized way of obtaining:

```
B = [1 0 0 
     0 1 0
     0 0 1
     2 0 0 
     0 2 0
     0 0 2
     3 0 0 
     0 3 0
     0 0 3]
```

Comment: Why not use a for loop?  Many years ago, vectorized expressions were faster than for loops, but not anymore.  A for loop will be easier to understand later.

Comment: @R.Schifini this is honestly a bad excuse for something, which can be easily vectorized. But I agree, the OP should have posted at least a solution using a loop to show what he've tried.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I wouldn't have put it that strongly. For this size input, any differences in execution speed would be negligible. Understandability/Maintainability is a very good thing. For larger inputs, speed may become more important.

Comment: @beaker You're right, but loops are boring :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way using [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
A = A.';
B = full(sparse(1:numel(A), repmat(1:size(A,1),1,size(A,2)), A(:)));
```

The original matrix is in `A`, and I transpose it so I can unroll the rows of each matrix properly for the next step.  I use `sparse` to declare what is non-zero in a matrix.  Specifically, we see that there is only one entry per row and so the row indices should range from 1 up to as many entries as there are in `A`.  The columns fluctuate from 1 up to the last column and repeat.  `mod` is certainly the way to go via thewaywewalk's solution, but I wanted to use `repmat` so that this is an independent solution from his approach.  As such, we create a vector for accessing the columns that goes from 1 up to as many columns as we have, and we repeat this for as many rows as we have.  These row and column index vectors are is going to dictate where the non-zero locations will appear.  Finally, what will go into each non-zero location are the elements of `A` unrolled in row major order, following the order dictated by the row and column index vectors.

Take note that in the `repmat` call, the rows and columns when calling `size` are reversed due to the transpose operation.

The result thus follows and we get:

```
>> B

B =

     1     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     3
     4     0     0
     0     5     0
     0     0     6
     7     0     0
     0     8     0
     0     0     9
```

Given the sparsity of the above problem, it may be faster to leave the matrix in `sparse` form and only convert using `full` if necessary.  There will be time spent to convert between the two formats so take that into consideration if you decide to benchmark.

Answer (score 5):

This is one solution using [**`mod`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) and [**`sub2ind`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
%// example data
data = reshape(1:9,3,3).' %'
n = 3;  %// assumed to be known

data =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

---

```
%// row indices
rows = 1:numel(data);
%// column indices
cols = mod(rows-1,n) + 1;
%// pre-allocation
out = zeros(n*n,n);
%// linear indices
linIdx = sub2ind(size(out),rows,cols);
%// assigning
out(linIdx) = data.'
```

---

```
out =

     1     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     3
     4     0     0
     0     5     0
     0     0     6
     7     0     0
     0     8     0
     0     0     9
```

---

Or if you prefer saving lines of code, instead of readability:

```
out = zeros(n*n,n);
out(sub2ind(size(out),1:numel(data),mod((1:numel(data))-1,n) + 1)) = data.'
```

---

Two other fast solutions, but not faster than the others:

```
%// #1
Z = blockproc(A,[1 size(A,2)],@(x) diag(x.data));

%// #2
n = size(A,2);
Z = zeros(n*n,n);
Z( repmat(logical(eye(n)),n,1) ) = A;
```

---

### For the sake of competition - Benchmark

```
function [t] = bench()
    A = magic(200);

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() thewaywewalk(A);
        @() lhcgeneva(A);
        @() rayryeng(A);
        @() rlbond(A);
    };

    % timeit
    t = zeros(4,1);
    for ii = 1:10;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
    format long
end

function Z = thewaywewalk(A) 
    n = size(A,2);
    rows = 1:numel(A);
    cols = mod(rows-1,n) + 1;
    Z = zeros(n*n,n);
    linIdx = sub2ind(size(Z),rows,cols);
    Z(linIdx) = A.';
end
function Z = lhcgeneva(A) 
    sz = size(A);
    Z = zeros(sz(1)*sz(2), sz(2));
    for i = 1 : sz(1)
        Z((i-1)*sz(2)+1:i*sz(2), :) = diag(A(i, :));
    end
end
function Z = rayryeng(A)  
    A = A.';
    Z = full(sparse(1:numel(A), repmat(1:size(A,2),1,size(A,1)), A(:)));
end
function Z = rlbond(A)  
    D = cellfun(@diag,mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1), 1), size(A,2)), 'UniformOutput', false);
    Z = vertcat(D{:});
end
```

---

```
ans =

   0.322633905428601  %// thewaywewalk
   0.550931853207228  %// lhcgeneva
   0.254718792359946  %// rayryeng - Winner!
   0.898236688657039  %// rlbond
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I guess thewaywewalk's benchmark leaves me only with a readability argument ;)

Edit using Beaker's suggestion:

```
data = [1 1 1
     2 2 2
     3 3 3];
sz = size(data);
z = zeros(sz(1)*sz(2), sz(2));
for i = 1 : sz(1)
    z((i-1)*sz(2)+1:i*sz(2), :) = diag(data(i, :));
end
```

Comment: Can you provide benchmarks with the `for` loop code compared to the other approaches? How do you know it's faster?

Comment: tic toc shows differences of about 5 fold speed up with respect to thewaywewalk's answer and about 30 fold speedup with respect to rlbond's answer

Comment: Can't you just do ` ... = diag(data(i, :))`?

Comment: Agreed.  You can just do `diag(data(i,:))`.  `diag` will convert a row vector into a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Right, that makes the most sense then obviously

Comment: I expected rlbond's answer to be slower.  `cellfun` is just a sloth.

Comment: BTW, this is a very smart way to do it, once you factor in the simpler `diag` call.  Very nicely done. +1.

Comment: For even better readability I would have used `z(end+1:end+3, :) = `, but then you lose the ability to preallocate.

Comment: I'm still showing a clear advantage for thewaywewalk's solution in Octave.

Comment: That's interesting, I literally copied the code from both answers and mine runs 4x faster. I have no experience how Octave and Matlab compare on this though, do you know about any differences in the lower level implementation that could explain such a discrepancy?

Comment: I don't know of anything specifically for this case, but I know there are significant differences in the implementation.

Comment: @rayreng: Looks like you made the race, for big matrices in any case ;) Guess I should've tested against a bigger matrix, not just 3x3...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, which (for me) is faster than any of the methods benchmarked above (for large and small matrices) is

```
[m,n] = size(A);
Z(n,m*n) = 0;
for idx = 1:n
     Z(idx,((idx-1)*m+1):(idx*m)) = A(:,idx);
end
Z = reshape(Z,m*n,n);
```

Comment: This result is slightly incorrect.  Though you are grabbing each row of `A` at a time, the way you are populating `Z` and the reshaping results in the appearance that you're accessing the values column wise and populating the array.  Try it on `A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`, for your solution the non-zero elements are read out as `1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9` and not `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

Comment: There we go.  Works now.

Comment: Had the indexing around the wrong way.  Now fixed in the above snippet.  Doesn't change the timing though.

Comment: That's interesting. On my machine, they're almost the same.  Nevertheless, this is a good way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts A to a cell array of row vectors, applies the `diag` function to each, and then stacks them:

```
D = cellfun(@diag,mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1), 1), size(A,2)), 'UniformOutput', false);
B = vertcat(D{:});
```

Results:

```
B =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     2     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     2
     3     0     0
     0     3     0
     0     0     3
```